# MongoTemplate upsert doesn't populate audit fields

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using upsert functionality of mongotemplate. Even though my class has Audit annotations (@createdby, @createddate etc.) it is not setting those fields. Could you please let me know how to achieve that?

I have checked the URL https://poornasubhash.blogspot.com/2013/06/spring-mongodb-auditing-and-extensions.html?showComment=1505259058777#c576019797296140099. It is from 2013 so is there any better alternative available now?

Comment: Hi @Debopam did you find a solution to the above? Thanks in advance!